# Does retriever-augmented generation enable the LLM to violate my data privacy?

Tags: open-ai

I understand in RAG, documents are sent (perhaps in embedded form?) to an LLM.
Supposing one uses openAI as in [this popular demo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo), would it send my data to them, thus with a potential data privacy risk?

[image]
(source: [ML6](https://blog.ml6.eu/leveraging-llms-on-your-domain-specific-knowledge-base-4441c8837b47))

Comment: Are documents sent in embedded form in your setting? If the text itself gets sent then, yes, it could be a privacy risk. If they're sent in an embedded form, then that's a more complicated question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that specific demo, but RAG usually works by adding retrieved documents directly into the LLM context. You should assume the process would result in documents being sent in text form to OpenAI.